# Problems with overloading [] operator (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, class, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write a small class "Array", but I have a problem when I want to overload [] operator for this class. The returned value must has `int` value but it has `Array&`.

There is my code:

Array.h:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include "QTableWidget"

class Array
{
public:
    Array();
    Array(int size);
    Array(int size, int start, int step);
    ~Array();

    int maxValue();
    int minValue();
    int averageValue();
    void chooseSort();
    void bubbleSort();
    void setSize(int size);
    int getSize();
    int getValue(int pos);
    void scalar(int number);

    Array operator +(Array &other);
    Array operator -(Array &other);
    Array operator *(int number);
    int& operator [](int index);

    Array(const Array &other);

    friend QTableWidget *operator <<(QTableWidget *widget, Array &other);
    friend QTableWidget *operator >>(QTableWidget *widget, Array &other);

private:
    void swap(int *a, int *b);

    int *array;
    int size;
};

#endif // ARRAY_H
```

My overloaded opeator in Array.cpp:

```
    int& Array::operator [](int index)
    {
        return (array[index]);
    }
```

And the function in which I have an error (MainForm.cpp, I write in Qt, but it doen't matter):

```
void MainForm::on_GetValue_released()
{
    int index = ui->ValueEdit->text().toInt();
    if(index > currentArr->getSize())return;
    int numer = currentArr[index];
    ui->ValueEdit->setText(QString::number(number));
}
```

And the error I have:
[image]

What I should do to have a correct answer?

Comment: `(*currentArr)[index];` one line above you are using `->`, you have to dereference object before calling `[]`, or `currentArr->operator[](index)`.

Comment: For a [mcve] the type of `currentArr` is missing. And yes, it is an important detail for your question.

Comment: @Werner Henze: I assume it is of type Array (so his or her own class Array implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My currentArr is a pointer, so I must do this: (*currentArr)[index];